# Cannot communicate backend and frontend on Docker

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I have two projects I have to dockerize, I suspect there is a problem between nginx port-forwarding, I am newbie on this subject and the Dockefiles are the following:

// Dockerfile NodeJS (Backend)

```
FROM alpine as node-build
RUN apk add --update nodejs npm
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

// Dockerfile Angular (Frontend)

```
FROM node:16-alpine as frontend
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run frontend

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=frontend /app/dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
```

// Docker compose

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: './backend'
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  frontend:
    build:
      context: './frontend'
    ports:
    - "4200:80"
```

//Proxy on frontend (/frontend/proxy.config.json)

```
{
  "/enviroment/*":{
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "loglevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

How can I make them communicate between?

Comment: Is that `http://localhost:3000` URL being built into your front-end application somehow?  Is there a specific error message you get (copy the text from the browser's error console)?  I'd broadly expect this setup to work, for a browser-based application, where the browser runs on the same host as the containers.

Comment: No, it is made on backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the Docker environment named "frontend", `localhost` refers to the container named "frontend", *not* to the Docker host (your server / local computer). It's on a separated network from its host. Segregating containers from each other and the host is a big part of containerization.

You *could* have Angular pass the request to your server / local computer, by connecting to its 'gateway IP address', but there is a better way: have Angular's proxy talk to the backend server. It's on the same network.

Docker Compose makes this easy by making every service available to containers in the same docker-compose.yml under a hostname, named identical to the service name:

```
{
  "/enviroment/*":{
    "target": "http://backend:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "loglevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Likewise, you could go into the container named "backend" and ping the hostname `frontend`.

You do not need to forward ports to do this, just like how you don't need to port forward within your home LAN. If you wanted to, you could remove the `"3000:3000"` mapping and Angular would still be able to communicate to `backend:3000` (but of course, then you wouldn't be able to do access `localhost:3000` from your own computer, which is *not* on the network Docker-compose has set up).

---

Having said that, your Dockerfile doesn't start the proxy process and the `proxyconfig.json` file isn't used at all.

You have a couple of options:

1. Run the development proxy in production (bad idea).
2. Run the backend on a domain (`api.example.com`) and the frontend on another (`example.com`) and change your app to load API requests from `https://api.example.com`. Easy to do although you need to worry about CORS.
3. You're using nginx to serve your static assets. It can also, just like the development server, proxy requests. In this case to your API.

If all requests to your API start with `/api` you could just do this:

```nginx
location / {
  # Any URL that isn't found falls back to the index page.
  # That way if you browse to example.com/about-us,
  # the index.html page is loaded, not a 404.
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
location /api {
  # A request like /api/users is forwarded to the backend.
  proxy_pass http://backend:3000;
}

# If you don't want the backend to receive "/api/users" but
# "/users" then this should work:
# location /api/ { proxy_pass http://backend:3000/; }
# (Note the two new trailing slashes.)
```

You might need to add more settings, such as a `client_max_body_size` if you have uploads. That's all specific to your app and out of scope for this single answer. [The documentation on Angular deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) has a lot of information, not all of it relevant to your use-case, but it's worth a skim.

Comment: While everything you say about Docker networking is correct, in a typical Angular application, the actual Javascript code is running in a browser; that's outside Docker and can't use Docker networking, and the `ports:` are required here.

Comment: What am I missing? they are still uncommunicated, can you take a look on my code please? maybe I am missing some stuff

Comment: While true, @DavidMaze , the configuration file `proxy.config.json`, is for a separate process used during development [to proxy requests from the Angular dev server to an API](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server). That way you can serve static (hot-reloaded) files and API responses from the same server and don't need to worry about CORS / cross-site cookies / etc. The proxy itself is, of course, not in-browser.

Comment: @M.Mariscal on further inspection, you're not actually _using_ that `proxy.config.json` file. If this is meant to be a production app, not for development, that's a good thing. In that case, you need to either expose the API to the world (eg. `api.example.com`) or you could use the Nginx instance you already have to proxy (`example.com/api` -> forward to backend). I've added an example to the answer above.